# Error when load Gradle project using Intellij

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I am trying to import a Gradle project into my IntelliJ. My settings are shown below:

[image]

However, when I click *Finish* button, I get the following error:

[image]

As you can see, I am using JDK 1.8 with Gradle 4.7 (installed by homebrew) on a Mac. Any idea what is causing this error?

Comment: What happens when you run `gradle clean build` in your `~/Code` directory?

Comment: @saw303, if I run `grade clean build` under root directory, I got error `FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'clean' not found in root project `. However, I can successfully run `gradle build`. But when I load the project in IntelliJ, I got the same error.

Comment: Please share the content of idea.log.